# How would you most efficiently store latitude and longitude data?

Tags: latitude-longitude, space-efficiency

This question comes from a homework assignment I was given. You can base your storage system off of one of the three following formats:

DD MM SS.S

DD MM.MMM

DD.DDDDD

You want to maximize the amount of data you can store by using as few bytes as possible.

My solution is based off the first format. I used 3 bytes for latitude: 8 bits for the DD (-90 to 90), 6 bits for the MM (0-59), and 10 bits for the SS.S (0-59.9). I then used 25 bits for the longitude: 9 bits for the DDD (-180 to 180), 6 bits for the MM, and 10 for the SS.S. This solution doesn't fit nicely on a byte border, but I figured the next reading can be stored immediately following the previous one, and 8 readings would use only 49 bytes.

I'm curious what methods others can come up. Is there a more efficient method to storing this data? As a note, I considered an offset based storage, but the problem gave no indication of how much the values may change between readings, so I'm assuming any change is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggested method is not optimal. You are using 10 bits (1024 possible values) to store a value in the range (0..599). This is a waste of space.

If you'll use 3 bytes for latitude, you should map the range [0, 2^24-1] to the range [-90, 90]. Hence each of the 2^24 values represents 180/2^24 degrees, which is 0.086 seconds.

If you want only 0.1 second accuracy, you'll need 23 bits for latitudes and 24 bits for longitudes (you'll get 0.077 seconds accuracy). That's 47 bit total instead of your 49 bits, with better accuracy.

**Can we do even better?**

The exact number of bits needed for 0.1 second accuracy is log2(180*60*60*10 * 360*60*60*10) < 46.256. Which means that you can use 46256 bits (5782 bytes) to store 1000 (lat,lon) pairs, but the mathematics involved will require dealing with very large integers.

**Can we do even better?**

It depends. If your data set has concentrations, you can store only some points and relative distances from these points, using less bits. Clustering algorithms should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to existing technology:

If you used [half precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format) [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) to store only the DD.DDDDD data, you can be a lot more space-efficent, but you'd have to accept an [exponent bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) of 15, which means: The coordinates stored might not be exact, but at an offset from the original value.

This is due to the way floating point numbers are stored, essentially: A normalized *significant* is multiplied by an *exponent* to result in a number, instead of just storing a single value (as in integer numbers, the way you calculated the numbers for your solution).

The next highest commonly used floating point number mechanism uses 32 bits (the type "float" in many programming languages) - still efficient, but larger than your custom format.

If, however, you would design your own custom floating point type as well, and you gradually added more bits, your results would become more exact and it would STILL be more efficient than the solution you first found.  Just play around with the number of bits used for significant and exponent, and find out how close your fp approximations come to the desired result in degrees!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is for a large number of readings, then you may try a differential approach. Start with an absolute location, and then start saving incremental changes, which should ideally require less bits, depending on the nature of the changes. This is effectively compressing the stream. But somehow I don't think that's what this homework is about.