# How to render a map with a lot of marker quickly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, google-maps, activerecord

So, I have a google map with a lot of markers, sometimes 500 000. I use markerclusterer to make it readable.

But processing the 500k results into a json file in order to feed google map takes forever.

Any idea how to speed up the process ?

Comment: I would suggest you be more specific. Do you know what's making the process slow? the active record query? the json data? or the actual javascript rendering in google maps?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few optimizations:

1. **Use raw data**, not objects/models. Mapping data from the database onto objects takes *a lot* of time. You can eliminate that by using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` to query the database.
2. [**Russian doll caching**](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/russian-doll-caching-cache-digests-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) is great for large datasets. You can cache individual records and groups of records. See ["How key-based cache expiration works"](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) for some good advise about cache expiration. Combine it with some in-memory cache like memcached and the results will be much faster.
3. **Send as little data as possible**. With 500k records every extra byte per record will result in half a Megabyte of extra traffic. So instead of full-blown, descriptive JSON better return an array of arrays. Example: `[[<lan1>, <lng1>, <id>], [<lat2>, ...], ...]`
4. **Only render markers within the current bounds**. Let's assume 500k records. If you send all of them to the client, that will be [at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930210/how-would-you-most-efficiently-store-latitude-and-longitude-data) 500,000 * 47bit ~ 2.8MB of data encoded as string/JSON, which will be much larger. So instead of sending all records, wait for the `idle` event of the Google Maps and load only the records/markers within the current bounds from the server. See the link Andrew posted in the comments.
5. Of course, **gzip** the HTTP response.